# Splitting PDF file into single pages using PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, split, pypdf

I'm trying to split a 3 page PDF into 3 separate PDF files. I have been trying to use the following code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf_file = open('Sample.pdf','rb')
pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()


pageNumbers = pdf_reader.getNumPages()

for i in range (pageNumbers):
    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(i))
    split_motive = open('Sample_' + str(i+1) + '.pdf','wb')
    pdf_writer.write(split_motive)
    split_motive.close()

pdf_file.close()
```

But that always seems to generate 3 PDF files:

1. The first page of the source PDF
2. The first and second page of the source PDF
3. The first, second and third page of the source PDF

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Move `pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()` into the loop body.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf_file = open('Sample.pdf','rb')
pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)


pageNumbers = pdf_reader.getNumPages()

for i in range (pageNumbers):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(i))
    split_motive = open('Sample_' + str(i+1) + '.pdf','wb')
    pdf_writer.write(split_motive)
    split_motive.close()

pdf_file.close()
```

Comment: I would also suggest a context manager for both `pdf_file` and `split_motive`, `with open(...) as ...:`

Comment: I've already tried to put `pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()` into the loop body. But then I get this very long error: _ File "C:\Users\Linda\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 557, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, data[i])
  File "C:\Users\Linda\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 575, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    if data.pdf.stream.closed:
AttributeError: 'PdfFileWriter' object has no attribute 'stream'
>>> _ and this is only the last few lines. Context managers I'm not experienced with but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Am I the only one getting this huge error message when I do it exactly as suggested in Answer 1?